Error: Unknown variable ... There is no variable named "var"
I got the Terraform error, the details is as following
variables.tf:
variable "acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges" {
  description = "List of IP CIDR ranges to allow access to the Azure Container Registry."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["203.0.113.5", "15.230.15.29/32"] # Replace with your list of IP CIDR ranges
}

acr_contrainer.tf:
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "main" {
  name                          = local.registry_name
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  sku                           = "Premium"
  admin_enabled                 = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true

  tags = local.default_tags
  
  network_rule_set {
    default_action = "Deny"

    dynamic "ip_rule" {
      for_each = var.acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges
      content {
        action   = "Allow"
        ip_range = ip_rule.value
      }
    }
  }
}

Got error:
│ Error: Unknown variable
│ 
│   on container_registry.tf line 16, in resource "azurerm_container_registry" "main":
│   16:       for_each = var.acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges
│ 
│ There is no variable named "var".
╵


are both the files in the same directory?

Can you try updating ip_rule.value to ip in the dynamic block @carlche issue seems to be with the way you are referencing it
Refer:https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20721


Unknown variable issue while referencing IP CIDR ranges to container registry using terraform

The issue seems to be with the way youre mactching network_rule_set and ip_rule in the configuration in a simple way ip_rule inside network_rule_set could not be dynamically configured using the dynamic block.
As per the github when ip_rule attribute as a list of objects using a for loop, directlly defining the allowed IP rules without relying on a dynamic block whcih over comes the blocker you faced using ip_rule .
Demo configuration:
variable "acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges" {
  description = "List of IP CIDR ranges to allow access to the Azure Container Registry."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["203.0.113.5/32", "15.230.15.29/32"] 
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "main" {
  name                          = "vinayacr143" 
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                           = "Premium"
  admin_enabled                 = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true

  network_rule_set {
    default_action = "Deny"

    ip_rule = [
      for ip in var.acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges : {
        action   = "Allow"
        ip_range = ip
      }
    ]
  }
}

Deployment:


Refer:
Dynamic block with for_each within network_rule_set inside azurerm_container_registry won't work · Issue #20721 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm · GitHub
Terraform – Simplified Azure Container Registry (ACR) Deployment · Jorge Bernhardt
Azure terraform module for container registry - dynamic block doesn’t remove IP addresses when emptying white listed IP list to complete zero - Stack Overflow

Thanks Vinay B, this worked, I use the same approach.

This might not work. I don't have access to Azure, to test before posting. We only use AWS and GCP. But this is the dynamic block syntax I usually use.
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "main" {
  name                          = local.registry_name
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  sku                           = "Premium"
  admin_enabled                 = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true

  tags = local.default_tags
  
  network_rule_set {
    default_action = "Deny"
    
    for_each = var.acr_registry_allowed_ip_ranges
    
    dynamic "ip_rule" {
      for_each = each.value.ip_rule
      content {
        action   = "Allow"
        ip_range = ip_rule.value.default
      }
    }
  }
}

So, you want to put the for_each that goes through your variable outside dynamic block, and inside, your for_each would be each.value.DYNAMIC_BLOCK_NAME and in the content block you would refer to each value as DYNAMIC_BLOCK_NAME.value.EACH_PARAMETER_KEY
